# How to add multiple polygons to a (Google) map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, polygon

I am trying to add multiple polygons to a map by touch click, but I can only add one. If I click on the screen to create, it fills the new coordinate in the previous polygon.

```
 map1.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        coorNoGo.add(latLng);
        PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
        polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.RED);
        polygonOptions.addAll(coorNoGo);
        Polygon NoGo = map1.addPolygon((polygonOptions));

    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, but this is not the same issu i face, i don't understand why i have only one polygon

Comment: I solve it, i add a longclick to clear previous polygon's coordinate and it works perfectly